# bitwise operation inside the string in python

Tags: python, string, bitwise-operators

s = "1 ^ 0 ^ 1 ^ 1 & 0 | 1 "

How to perform the operation in s if s is a string in python ?

my problem is to replace a with bitwise and , b with bitwise or , and c with bitwise or and perform the action .

```py
k = '1C0C1C1A0B1'
alpha = []
for i in range(len(k)):
    p = k[i]
    alpha.append(p)

for i in range(len(alpha)):
    if alpha[i] == 'A':
        alpha[i] = '&'
    if alpha[i] == 'B':
        alpha[i] = '|'
    if alpha[i] == 'C':
        alpha[i] = '^'

s = " ".join(map(str, alpha))
print(s)
```

i tried this above code i don't know how to proceed further. Please help me.

Comment: Is order of operations an issue here, or do they all have the same precedence?

Comment: note: you can make the alpha list like so: `alpha = list(k)`. Lines 2 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval command.

Python’s eval() is an incredibly useful tool, the function has some **important security implications** that you should consider before using it.
https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/

```py
k = '1C0C1C1A0B1'
s = k.replace('A', '&').replace('B', '|').replace('C','^')
eval(s)
# output : 1
```

security checking with regex

```py
import re
regex = r"^((0|1)[A-C])*(0|1)$"
k = '1C0C1C1A0B1'

# Input control
match = re.match(regex, k)
if not match:
    raise Exception("Input format error") 


s = k.replace('A', '&').replace('B', '|').replace('C','^')
eval(s)
# output : 1
```

Comment: Without eval function, you would have to make Abstract Syntax Tree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree .

Comment: And then the user inputs `__import__("os").system("rm -rf --no-preserve-root /")` and you're sad.

Comment: Ya, at the very least, you should sanitize all non-expected input characters and either just drop them, or raise an error if there's anything unexpected. All it takes is the user doing something stupid like piping input into your program from an untrusted source, and suddenly you have a vulnerability (although, a very unlikely one).